# Protractor: Getting [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning and test run is terminated randomly

Tags: node.js, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, gruntjs, protractor

I am using latest protractor version 5.2.2 with node 8.9.3 and npm 5.6.0
I have about 30 test suites and each of them have around 150 test cases.
All of them run fine on my local but when I run them on Jenkins machines using grunt which have Windows and exactly same node and protractor version I get the below error randomly and the execution gets stuck until I kill the Jenkins job.

```
(node:3060) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TimeoutError: timeout
(Session info: chrome=63.0.3239.84)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522940 
(1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
(node:3060) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:3060) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
```

The failures occur randomly and not after a certain test case. So sometimes it will fail at starting only and sometimes in middle and sometimes on the last test case.

I have tried using both *seleniumAddress* and *direcConnect* but same issue.
This has wasted so much of my time and still am stuck where I started.
Any help here will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error stack had told you the root cause 'A Jasmine spec timed out'.  It means some spec take much time to complete which exceed the time out.

I think the website running on Jenkins machine slow than your local.

Please read from Protractor website link at below, you will find the solution. 
http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts#timeouts-from-jasmine

```
exports.config = {

    allScriptsTimeout: 120 * 1000,

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120 * 1000,
        onComplete: null,
        isVerbose: true,
        showColors: true,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        realtimeFailure: true
    },
    ... 
};
```

Comment: I have the following in my conf.js and I dont think it will take more time than this to load as it is running locally.

    ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true
    allScriptsTimeout: 5000000
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 4000000

Comment: Did you use Jasmine and put defaultTimeoutInterval inside jasmineNodeOpts as above?

Comment: yes I have 


`jasmineNodeOpts: {

    isVerbose: true,

    showColors: true,

    includeStackTrace: true,

    defaultTimeoutInterval: 4000000

  },`

Comment: Your configure are correct, the possible reason i can only doubt now is protractor, Maybe you can try a lower version of Protractor not the latest.